# Reasonableness of Micropiles

Tags: science-based, propulsion, fission

In a few of Isaac Asimov's stories, including *The Martian Way*, he uses water as a reaction mass to provide sub-light travel, and he mentions that the water is heated using "micropiles".
Leaving aside the concerns of wide-scale industrial production of fissile material, is such a technology feasible?  Given enough time and engineering dedicated to the subject, is it physically possible for fissile materials to be configured such that their critical mass is very low, and the equipment needed to harness them is light enough to put on a rocket?
If it isn't is there something close, or is there a plausible application of hand-wavium?

Comment: Yes, the critical mass of a fissile material can be decreased using various techniques known to people who design atomic bombs; on the other hand, I have never heard of a way to decrease it by a factor of ten or more -- which means that it remains on the order of kilograms. But then, why would you want a small critical mass of fissile material when you are not making a bomb?

Comment: You just gave an example of "*plausible application of hand-wavium.*"  (micropiles). The fact that you are asking the question means the author made it plausible enough for you to be willing to suspend disbelief.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the design of your power supply, the mass you need to output useful energy may not be that high. [Plutonium-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238) is often used in small power supplies based on the principle of [radioisotope thermoelectric generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) (where power is harvested directly from the decay heat of the material, rather than heating water and drawing power from its physical expansion).

One reason RTGs are favored is that they can be extremely small. SNAP-3, the first operational RTG, had a plutonium payload of only 96 grams. Other applications included a test run of RTG-powered pacemakers. The US maintains two strategic reserves of Pu-238, one of which is earmarked for civil spaceflight and totals about 35kg. From the 1kg with the highest purity, NASA intends to supply three missions, including the recently-launched Perseverance rover. To maintain reserves, they intend to scale up production at Oak Ridge National Laboratory to 1.5kg/year. You get the idea - RTGs are not massive.

The first proper RTGs weren't developed until 1954, a few years after the story, but Asimov may have heard about earlier proposals to capture power from the decay heat of subcritical masses of material.

Comment: I'm always flabbergasted RTGs were used in light houses. Either lightouses are way more important than I thought they were, or they are not nearly as mundane as I think they are.

Comment: @DKNguyen *now* lighthouses aren't as critical, but in pre-GPS era lighthouses are super important for navigation safety in remote locations, and there's a big time gap where we have atomic tech but not GPS.

Comment: @DKNguyen As well as what Peteris said, for an electrically powered lighthouse in a very remote location, an RTG is still a rather good choice of power as it requires far less work to keep running than something like a gas powered generator or tidal energy capture system.

Answer (score 4):

The [NERVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NERVA) ("Nuclear Engine for Rocket Vehicle Application") project was run by NASA and the AEC between the late 1950s and 1973. It was based on a nuclear thermal rocket, which is simply a nuclear reactor used to heat reaction mass: hydrogen is the most efficient substance, but water works too. The project ended largely because of budget politics. When it was shut down, a project to build an engine for flight tests was going well.

This kind of nuclear rocket was an obvious possibility as soon as nuclear reactors were invented. It isn't the best possible nuclear rocket, but it is simple in principle, and about twice as efficient as the best chemical rockets. Asimov wrote *The Martian Way* in 1952, before the NERVA project started, so he was not specific about how his engines worked.

Answer (score 3):

**Your micro pile does not have to be an 'open' system to work** i.e. you do not have to physically pump water through the core to heat it.

Instead a sealed nuclear power unit be used to produce electricity which is then used to power **microwave antennas** in the reaction chamber with water used as the fuel. (Basically a souped up version of your kitchen microwave.) There is a company looking at this now for satellite thrusters.

In theory **Masers** (tuned to the appropriate frequency) could also be used instead to achieve the same effect - perhaps with higher exhaust velocities resulting. And you want the highest you can get of course.

The beauty of this system, assuming it can be perfected is that in theory you can use *any* fluid you want as fuel so long as you can tune the microwave emitters to the  proper absorption frequency. So your rocket could use water on an outward bound trip to say Jupiter and methane on the way back if its cheaper/easier to do so. And the actual 'drive' itself is potentially very robust and relatively simple to build and operate because it uses very well understood physics.

Answer (score 2):

While Asimov was writing fiction then, it is theoretically possible today to create something along these lines, such as "[Reactor on a chip](https://www.wired.com/2009/07/darpas-handheld-nuclear-fusion-reactor/)". It is also possible to use subcritical masses of fissile material and go critical by striking it with a beam of neutrons, for example using spallation from a particle accelerator to create an [accelerator driven nuclear reactor](https://www.world-nuclear.org/information-library/current-and-future-generation/accelerator-driven-nuclear-energy.aspx).

So a small, compact nuclear reactor which could be characterized as a "microreactor" is possible using currently known physics, and since the engine in the story is essentially a steam engine (water heated by the nuclear reactor to create a jet of superheated steam for rocket propulsion), then this isn't implausible at all.

The only actual issue (regardless of the heat source) is a steam rocket is rather inefficient (has a low ISP), and steam can be quite corrosive to the reactor parts if the reactor isn't designed properly. However, since water is fairly common throughout the Solar System, and presumably across the universe, then a rocket using nuclear energy to create superheated steam seems to be a sensible idea for a space faring civilization.